Discord.js bot joining voicechannel but does not play audio
My discord js bot won't play audio in the voice channel even though it joins; I do not get any errors in the console.
I recently switched from using a Windows machine to a Macos system. Does it have anything to do with permissions from the OS? I have fffmpeg installed and all the necessary dependancies that @/discordjs/voice needs, as well as all the right intents.
import {
  VoiceConnection,
  joinVoiceChannel,
  AudioPlayer,
  createAudioPlayer,
  NoSubscriberBehavior,
  createAudioResource,
} from "@discordjs/voice";
import { db } from "../../../database";
import { videos } from "../../../database/schema";
import type { VideoMetadataResult } from "yt-search";
import { Guild, VoiceBasedChannel } from "discord.js";
import { getVideos } from "../../../database/utils";
import playdl from "play-dl";

export class Player {
  guild = null;
  connection: VoiceConnection = null;
  voiceChannel = null;
  player = createAudioPlayer({
    behaviors: {
      noSubscriber: NoSubscriberBehavior.Stop,
    },
  });
  constructor(guild: Guild, voiceChannel: VoiceBasedChannel) {
    this.guild = guild;
    this.voiceChannel = voiceChannel;
  }

  async queue(video: VideoMetadataResult) {
    const videosCount = (await getVideos()).length;
    await db.insert(videos).values({
      url: video.url,
      authorName: video.author.name,
      title: video.title,
      seconds: video.seconds,
      index: videosCount,
    });
  }

  createConnection() {
    if (!this.voiceChannel) return;
    this.connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: this.voiceChannel.id,
      guildId: this.guild.id,
      selfDeaf: false,
      adapterCreator: this.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });
  }

  join() {
    if (!this.connection) this.createConnection();
  }

  async playNext() {
    const allVideos = (await getVideos()).sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index);
    this.join();

    if (!allVideos[0]) return;

    this.connection?.subscribe(this.player);

    const stream = await playdl.stream(allVideos[0].url, {
      discordPlayerCompatibility: true,
    });
    const audioSource = createAudioResource(stream.stream);

    this.player.play(audioSource);

    this.player.on("stateChange", (state) => {
      console.log(state);
    });
  }
}

